# Eagerly select all objects in entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

How I can select entire object graph in hibernate using one query? I set `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to all dependent object-type fields of my entity . But I also want to provide method which will select all objects EAGERLY (like specifying `FetchType.EAGER` on all fields). How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hibernate.initialize()` to load all lazily loaded properties of your object. I'm not sure how deep do you want to traverse your object graph, but I believe this would cover at least 80% of the practically useful cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named queries, for example if you have:

```
Class Teacher {
    List<Course> courses;
    List<Student> students;
}
```

use:

```
select t from Teacher t inner join fetch t.courses tcs inner join fetch t.students tss where ....
```

then you have Teachers with courses and students loaded eagerly and it does not depend on **fetch = FetchType.LAZY**

Answer (score 0):

We are using Ejb. If you call the getter for the lazy object, it is fetched from the database. The disadvantage is, that there is not only one query with joins, there is one querY per lazy fetched object.